# error: bash: echo: write error: Function not implemented

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualization

echo '1' > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.1/sriov_numvfs
I am using the above command but getting an error.

From the logs I get this message:
"vfio-pci 0000:01:00.0: Driver doesn't support SRIOV configuration via sysfs"

Can anyone please point me to the solution.

Thank you

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: From the logs I got this message : vfio-pci 0000:01:00.0: Driver doesn't support SRIOV configuration via sysfs

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have created a VF (virtual function) for the network interface used for SR-IOV.

You are trying to write 1 into the `sriov_numvfs` parameter, but looks like either the function is not supported in the device driver module, or the call is wrong.

Looking into [this](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/technology-briefs/xl710-sr-iov-config-guide-gbe-linux-brief.pdf) doc, page 12 has a similar command:

```
#echo 0 > /sys/class/net/device name/device/sriov_numvfs
```

As you can see, the `sriov_numvfs` lies in *sys/class/net* here. Check if its the right location and try to echo number without quotes too.

Also, check the */var/logs/messages* for any error messages appended there during the driver load. You might find something relevant to your issue there. Hope this helped.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am binding a device to dpdk, before that device is available in /sys/class .. and I am also able to create a VF. But , after binding that device to dpdk, I get this error which I mentioned.

Comment: I get this error in /var/log "vfio-pci 0000:01:00.0: Driver doesn't support SRIOV configuration via sysfs" Any solution to this ? Please